# Importing a Wordlist

Tags: python

I'm learning CS/Python on MIT's Open Courseware. They want me to design a hangman game and have given me some preliminary code for importing a wordlist and generating a random word from there. This code on its own returns an error: "can't have unbuffered text I/O." Here's the code:

```
import random
import string

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

def load_words():
     print("Loading word list from file...")
     # inFile: file
     inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
     # line: string
     line = inFile.readline()
     # wordlist: list of strings
     wordlist = string.split(line)
     print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
     return wordlist

def choose_word(wordlist):
     return random.choice(wordlist)
```

The MIT course does not use Python 3.0, which I am using, so there may be a problem  there; as you can see I've already updated "print" from a declaration to a function for compatibility with Python 3.0.

Comment: please post full trace :) You should also avoid using string module, just use line.split() instead.

Comment: It seems you can find the full trace at.... [XKCD](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=72920)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Python 3.0? If you're taking a course in Python 2.7, it'll be a lot easier to use 2.7. (And if you really do want Python3, why not 3.2 or later? 3.0 is buggy and clunky.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is thrown because you are trying to read a **text file** with buffering switched off (the third parameter set to 0):

```
inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
```

Replace the above line with

```
inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r')
```

and it should work.

From the python docs:

> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
>   **Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode)**, 1 to
>   select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1
>   to indicate the size of a fixed-size chunk buffer.

Comment: The error message actually tells you exactly what the Python2-vs.-3 difference is here; it's just that you have to know a whole lot to be able to _tell_ what it's telling you. Unlike Python 2, Python 3 can't do unbuffered text files, because "text files" now means "files decoded to Unicode on the fly" instead of just "files with newline conversion applied on the fly".

Answer (score 3):

Remove `0` from `open` built-in function call. From python docs:

> Buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
>   Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode).